# Where can tag proposals go?

Tags: support

Where should tag proposals be made?

(I want to suggest [dupli](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dupli) or [duplivert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplivert))

Comment: you add a tag, like any other tag, then submit the post. Then you click into the new tag and add an excerpt, which is then vetted by moderators.

Comment: "Creating the new tag 'dupli' requires at least 150 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead."

Comment: i'm not opposed to the tag, if you can write a concise excerpt for the tag wiki (and a longer description..if you feel strongly about it). I will add the tag to a post if you link it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is meta, anything about the site can be posted here if you are unsure or just curious, so you can post those here in the future and the community will respond.

Once you have the [privilege to create tags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), you can do so *if* you think your post is unique enough to merit a new tag.

Don't abuse this though, we keep strict tabs on the tags already in the system and as they are added. Often times you might find that your new tag can be generalized under a broader tag or the [other way around](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/should-the-tool-tag-be-removed/). That being said, you can also just leave a comment under your post suggesting that the tag be added and someone with the privilege will add it if it's necessary.

Additionally, you are ***not*** obligated to do so, but if you create a new tag, again, feel free to [create](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) the tag wiki for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the awesome new [Privileges page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you'll see [Create tags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), awarded at 150 reputation. With this privilege, you can create new tags simply by adding them to a question.

If you do not have the reputation to create a new tag, you can just leave a comment on your question asking someone with enough reputation to add the tag to your question for you.

There's even a [badge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) for creating a tag used by 50 questions.