# How are Tags read?

Tags: support, tags, questions, answers

If a question is asked, and a certain (what might be relevant) 'tag' is *not* added, does it mean that answers, relative to that missing 'tag', will be excluded (as being 'beyond the scope of the question')?

For example, in my question:  [How can I change the centre of rotation of objects during an animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/802/how-can-i-change-the-centre-of-rotation-of-objects-during-an-animation)  I thought the tag ' Animation' would suffice, along with the details in my question, but if there's a chance of solving the problem by scripting, would I only get a 'Scripting' answer by adding the 'Scripting' tag?

By the way, the answers I got work (I had already tried them previously), but in a very limited way, and don't really solve the problem. Now the question, and answers are just left hanging there!

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on what [Luke](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/213/12) said.. **Tags decide very little on the type of answer(s) you will get on a question.** For example, the question you linked *could* have had [rigging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rigging) or [constraints](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraints) added too, that didn't stop people from adding those solutions.

As he also said, it is just a fancy organization feature so don't depend too much on them when asking questions. For short term reasons, they help to set the scope of your question and possibly attract an audience and for long term reasons, they are nice filters for searching for answers etc.

Here are some simple dos and don'ts to keep in mind when tagging however..

### Do:

- tag with the closest related tag(s)
- use as many as you think you need to the maximum
- [create new tags if the current ones aren't good enough](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/191/12)
- retag the question as needed if you update it

### Don't:

- tag the question with what you are *expecting* as an answer unless it relates somehow
- use unrelated tags to fill space
- retag the question with the method that solved it unless it relates somehow

It is also worth noting that if anyone thinks additional tags are needed, they more than likely *will* be added.

Answer (score -1):

No, tags are simply used for organization. If a question is missing a tag, go ahead and retag it with the correct tag. If an question lacks a tag, the quality of the answers should not suffer (assuming the question body makes clear the question).