# Adding Tags Related to Answer

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it appropriate to edit in tags to a question that relate exculsively to an answer (or *the* answer of the question?

For example, I answered [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/101818/26640). It is properly tagged with [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles), [volumetrics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volumetrics), and [texture-coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-coordinates). My answer utilized Animation Nodes, which also has its own tag.

**Since the answer (and thus the page) now contain information about Animation Nodes, would it be appropriate to edit in the [animation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes) tag?**

I have seen this type of answer occur more often recently, where the solution uses a totally different method than the question was tagged, specifically with [animation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes), though I'm sure it also applies elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**. Tags describe the question. Just because you use X in your answer does not mean the question is about X, nor should it be tagged X.
[Should we retag questions with topics proposed in the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59333/278094)

Take your example question for instance. Say you added the [animation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes) tag, now I come along (knowing almost nothing about AN) thus I skip over that question entirely.

Or another instance, Its a modeling question. You write an answer using the knife tool, so you add the [knife-tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knife-tool) tag. I find it, and now I'm not sure if the OP really wanted to use the knife tool, maybe my boolean answer is not what he is looking for.

We all know there are lots of ways to do things. We should not be retagging questions, essentially limiting the scope of the answers, just because you used tool X.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The main Meta link is very helpful.

Comment: While I agree with this answer. I still think there is some wiggle room available tho I'm not sure how to best express it or even do this with existing functionality. See [my post here some 5 years ago](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-are-tags-read/215#215). Hmm. Maybe it's best to just be explicit and say no after all...